# OSCommerce STS template flow-How to get output of a box in html file

Tags: oscommerce

I am trying to explore STS template system.

What i need to do is simple.

I just want to show a banner/box in the right column which is added from the OSC admin.

I have done the following steps:

1. added a banner from admin banner manager.
2. created a file in the includes/boxes directory under name customBanner.php
3. added this line in column_right.php include(DIR_WS_BOXES . 'customBanner.php');
4. And finally added the following code to customBanner.php

---

```
<?php
if ($banner = tep_banner_exists('dynamic', '170x158')) {
?>
<br>
<table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td align="center"><?php echo tep_display_banner('static', $banner); ?></td>
</tr>
</table>
<?php
}
?>
```

This code is basically used for OSC without STS template.

Now i need to know how STS template giving output in php.html files e.g.`<td>$specialbox</td>`. I mean how this variable is getting value from the sts.
and how can i show advertisement box in the right column.

Answer (score 0):

You should add to the includes/modules/sts_inc/sts_user_code.php teh following code:

```
$sts->start_capture();
include(DIR_WS_INCLUDES . 'boxes/customBanner.php');
$sts->stop_capture('specialbox');
```

It also posible to use your own file to add this code but you should include its name in the admin->modules-> Default -> Files for normal template

Comment: Dear ZhenIT thanks alot for your help. it really helped me alot. actually i need to add two boxes added from admin. for a single box i had managed to add banner_only command in includes/sts_templates/full/index.php.html. But your answer made me explore sts more. can u plz plz plz help me know that how i can add two boxes.

Answer (score 0):

You could add as many boxes as you like in the same way:

```
$sts->start_capture();
include(DIR_WS_INCLUDES . 'boxes/customBanner.php');
$sts->stop_capture('box1');

$sts->start_capture();
include(DIR_WS_INCLUDES . 'boxes/OTHERcustomBanner.php');
$sts->stop_capture('box2');
```